# Removing legend box (border) in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I'm attempting to remove or 'turn off' the legend border in pgfplots, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.  I assume it will look something like this:

```
\begin{axis}[ legend style={?}]
```

where ? is a property related to the legend border (or box) that I can't seem to find.  The pgfplots help is really great, but I haven't seen this addressed anywhere.  Does anyone know how to accomplish this simple task?

Comment: to turn off the border around filled areas (a related question), there is a bug with the draw=none option. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99861/remove-border-around-area-legend-rectangle

Answer (score 66):

Try

```
\begin{axis}[ legend style={draw=none}]
```

That looks like it might be asking for no legend to be drawn at all but actually it just applies to the rectangle around the legend.

Comment: Good point. I have added that style to the pgfplots manual.