# Remove border around area legend rectangle

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I have a legend with the option `area legend` to draw a little rectangle in the legend instead of a line segment. There is a border around the rectangle I would like to either remove or make the same color as the actual rectangle.
How is this done?

Comment: How do you want some help? You didn't even provide any of the command used to draw this area!

Comment: the command is `area legend`

Comment: It does not: `\addplot +[fill=grey0, draw=none]`

Comment: @ManofOneWay using your command gives me "undefined control sequence"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To hide the border both in the plot and in the legend, you should use `draw opacity=0` in the `\addplot` options instead of `draw=none`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm] {standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [fill=yellow,draw opacity=0, area legend] coordinates {(0,0) (2,1) (4,1)} \closedcycle;
\addlegendentry{Plot}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is to change the `area legend` style so that `draw=none` actually takes effect. (Example taken from the `pgfplots` manual, page 173.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/area legend/.style={%
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \fill[##1] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.6cm,0.1cm);
        }%
    },
}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    area legend,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    domain=0:1,
    legend style={at={(0.03,0.97)},anchor=north west},
    axis on top,xmin=0]
\addplot[
    pattern=crosshatch dots,
    pattern color=blue,
    draw=none,
    samples=500] {sqrt(x)} \closedcycle;
\addplot[
    pattern=crosshatch,
    pattern color=blue!30!white,
    draw=blue!30!white] {x^2} \closedcycle;
\addplot[red,line legend] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
\legend{$\sqrt x$,$x^2$,$x$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Could you post this as a [bug report](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=224188&atid=1060656)?

Comment: @Jake I have: [Area Legend contains draw even though draw=none is given.](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3606422&group_id=224188&atid=1060656)